# How to find increasing volumes in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below is the sample data

```
 create table #sample (id int,Spenddate datetime, Balance int)

 insert into #sample values (1,getdate(),100)
 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+1,98)
 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+2,50)
 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+3,0)

 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+5,20)
 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+6,25)
 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+7,30)
 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+8,40)
 insert into #sample values (1,getdate()+9,55)
```

I need to find the continuous increases ...

Actually the real time situation is,

Instead of debiting, somehow system mistakenly crediting the amount to the customer after balance went to zero. So I need to find affected records.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using lag and lead function in sql server 2012

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2877/sql-server-analysis-serviceslead-lag-openingperiod-closingperiod-time-related-functions/
share|edit

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `lag()` function, But you don't have it in SQL Server 2008.  You can get the same effect with a correlated subquery or cross apply.  So the same query should get all records that have a larger balance than the previously reported balance:

```
select *
from (select v.*,
             (select top 1 v2.balance
              from #values v2
              where v2.id = v.id and v2.SpendDate < v.SpendDate
              order by v2.SpendDate desc
             ) as prev_balance
      from #values v
     ) v
where prev_balance < balance;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using lag and lead function in sql server 2012

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2877/sql-server-analysis-serviceslead-lag-openingperiod-closingperiod-time-related-functions/